# Facebook API v2.12 permission error

Tags: facebook, api, permissions

I have requested api for retreive data from open facebook group. I know that user_managed_groups permission should be approved by facebook, but if I add someone as tester they should have that permission to read the group. Or am I wrong?

Even if the test user member of group with v2.12 api call I can't retreive any data, because it says permission denied. When I try v2.11 ( of course only in graph explorer ) then the data appears.

Is this happens because user_managed_groups is not enough permission to give to the test user?
[This is with v2.12 api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAWtl.png)

Comment: The test user need to grant your app user_managed_groups permission. But it will only give you access to the users groups that they manage. Not other groups

Comment: The test user is in the group which I want to fetch.

Comment: Are they admin of the group? user_managed_groups only let that user fetch posts in groups that they are admin of.

Comment: Probably not. Maybe thats the problem. Thank you.